# Why does flask_socketio.disconnect prevent the thread from completing?

Tags: python, flask-socketio, gevent-socketio, python-socketio

I have the following system: **[Client] - [Web Server] - [Connecotr]**.

A connector is a kind of intermediate code between a web server and a data source.

I need to monitor the server connection with the connector. If the connection is lost, then I must notify the client.

Communication between the web server and the connector is organized using socketio.

The problem is that if the connector stops working, then the web server will know about it only after a minute (this is in the best case).

I decided that the server should check the status of the connector every second.

When the connector is connected on the server, a background task starts. The essence of the task: every second: 1) fix the time; 2) save the fixed time to the stack; 3) send the echo message to the connector. (see server.background_thread)

The connector accepts the echo message and time stamp as a parameter and sends an echo message to the web server, as the parameter it passes the time stamp that it received. (see client.echo)

The web server receives an echo message, if the timestamp is equal to the last value in the stack, then this value is removed from the stack. (see server.on_echo_connector)

On the web server, at each iteration, the stack size is checked (see server.background_thread). If it is greater than 5, then this means that the connector did not respond to the echo message 5 times, we believe that the connector is unavailable, and disconnect from it.

When the server realizes that the connector is unavailable, it is necessary to terminate the thread that sent echo messages to the connector.

Once the stack size is greater than 5, I exit the infinite loop and call `flask_socketio.disconnect (connector_sid, '/ connector')`. After this call nothing works (e.g. `print`)

In the `on_disconnect_connector` (server) method, `thread.join()` is called and never terminates.

And I need to complete the thread, so that when the connector is started again, it will connect successfully and everything starts all over again.

How to solve this problem?

server

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import threading
import time
import collections
from datetime import datetime

import flask
import flask_socketio

def get_unix_time():
    return int(time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple()))

class Stack(collections.deque):

    def __init__(self, iterable=(), maxlen=None):
        collections.deque.__init__(self, iterable, maxlen)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self)

    @property
    def empty(self):
        return self.size == 0

    @property
    def head(self):
        return self[-1]

    @property
    def tail(self):
        return self[0]

    def push(self, x):
        self.append(x)

# SERVER

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
sio = flask_socketio.SocketIO(app, async_mode='gevent')

connector_sid = None
echo_stack = Stack()

thread = None
thread_lock = threading.Lock()


def background_thread(app):
    time.sleep(2)  # delay for normal connection

    while True:
        if echo_stack.size >= 5:
            break
        time_ = get_unix_time()
        echo_stack.push(time_)
        sio.emit('echo', time_, namespace='/connector')
        sio.sleep(1)

    with app.app_context():
        flask_socketio.disconnect(connector_sid, '/connector')


@sio.on('connect', namespace='/connector')
def on_connect_connector():
    """Connector connection event handler."""
    global connector_sid, thread
    print 'Attempt to connect a connector {}...'.format(request.sid)

    # if the connector is already connected, reject the connection
    if connector_sid is not None:
        print 'Connection for connector {} rejected'.format(request.sid)
        return False
        # raise flask_socketio.ConnectionRefusedError('Connector already connected')

    connector_sid = request.sid
    print('Connector {} connected'.format(request.sid))

    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = sio.start_background_task(
                background_thread, current_app._get_current_object())

    # notify clients about connecting a connector
    sio.emit('set_connector_status', True, namespace='/client')


@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/connector')
def on_disconnect_connector():
    """Connector disconnect event handler."""
    global connector_sid, thread

    print 'start join'
    thread.join()
    print 'end join'
    thread = None
    print 'after disconet:', thread

    connector_sid = None

    echo_stack.clear()

    print('Connector {} disconnect'.format(request.sid))

    # notify clients of disconnected connector
    sio.emit('set_connector_status', False, namespace='/client')


@sio.on('echo', namespace='/connector')
def on_echo_connector(time_):
    if not echo_stack.empty:
        if echo_stack.head == time_:
            echo_stack.pop()


@sio.on('message', namespace='/connector')
def on_message_connector(cnt):
    # print 'Msg: {}'.format(cnt)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app)
```

client

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import threading
import time

import socketio
import socketio.exceptions

sio = socketio.Client()
thread = None
thread_lock = threading.Lock()
work = False


def background_thread():
    # example task
    cnt = 0
    while work:
        cnt += 1
        if cnt % 10 == 0:
            sio.emit('message', cnt // 10, namespace='/connector')
        sio.sleep(0.1)


@sio.on('connect', namespace='/connector')
def on_connect():
    """Server connection event handler."""
    global thread, work

    print '\n-----            Connected to server            -----' \
          '\n----- My SID:  {} -----\n'.format(sio.sid)

    work = True  # set flag

    # run test task
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = sio.start_background_task(background_thread)


@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/connector')
def on_disconnect():
    """Server disconnect event handler."""
    global thread, work

    # clear the work flag so that at the next iteration the endless loop ends
    work = False
    thread.join()
    thread = None

    # disconnect from server
    sio.disconnect()
    print '\n-----         Disconnected from server          -----\n'

    # switch to the mode of infinite attempts to connect to the server
    main()


@sio.on('echo', namespace='/connector')
def on_echo(time_):
    sio.emit('echo', time_, namespace='/connector')


def main():
    while True:
        try:
            sio.connect('http://localhost:5000/connector',
                        namespaces=['/connector'])
            sio.wait()
        except socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print 'Trying to connect to the server...'
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print '\n---------- EXIT ---------\n'
            sys.exit()
        except Exception as e:
            print e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print '\n---------- START CLIENT ----------\n'
    main()
```

Python 2.7

Comment: Why does it take one minute to detect a disconnection? This is only the case for HTTP connections, but when the connection is on WebSocket a disconnection is detected immediately. Have you verified if your client connects over WebSocket?

Comment: @Miguel, no, are you talking about "connection_transports" for the client?

Comment: @Miguel, connection_transports == None. I updated the client connection to sio.connect('http: // localhost:5000/connector', namespaces=['/connector'], transports = ['websocket']). But now the client does not even connect to the server. After each connection, "sio.connected == True", but the server does not see the client, and the client connects endlessly in a loop.

Comment: No, what I was asking is if your server supports connections over WebSocket. For this to work you need to use the eventlet or gevent web servers, if you use the Flask web server WebSocket isn't supported.

Comment: @Miguel, yes, I have the gevent and gevent-websocket packages installed. The problem was that the client did not switch to the websocket transport. I found a solution to this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to install an additional library for the client ([see](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/254#issuecomment-465882385))

```
pip install "python-socketio[client]"
```

Thanks to this library, the WebSocket transport works. Now disconnecting the connector is immediately visible.